# How can I find the source of a Qt5 signal during gdb session?

Tags: gdb, qt5, signals-slots

I have set a break-point on a **slot** method and started up **gdb** to debug my **Qt5** application. I would like to know from where in the code this slot gets called from (via the Qt5 **signal** system).

My naive approach ends in suspension of the program at the break-point, but the stack-trace is all Qt5 internals with no clue as to which part of the program actually sent the signal to this slot (or weather it was a queued or direct invocation:

[image]

Is this at all possible? How?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should mark some of the useful answers as accepted in order to generate more willingness to help from other users.

Comment: There is only one answer and i am hoping for an actual answer, not a suggestion. Of course i will hinor the best alternative, but imo its a bit early.

Comment: I'm not talking about just this question.

Comment: Me neither. Look at the dates.

Comment: Tried creating a global `QSignalSpy` and placing checking its value in the debugger when stepping through the slot. It also doesn't tell you the source location, just lists the signals that were emitted.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATED**

The only time you won't see the signal caller in the stack backtrace is when the connection is queued.

For direct connections you should see something like this:

```
0 Receiver::baz()           <-- slot function that received the signal
1 Receiver::qt_static_metacall()
2 QMetaObject::activate()
3 Sender::bar()             <-- function with the name of the signal
4 Sender::foo()             <-- function that called emit
5 QWidget::event()
...
```

For queued connections, the situation is more complicated. But you can add the following to your slot:

```
QString __sender__ = sender()->metaObject()->className();
```

This will give you class name of the object, which had sent the signal. You can make it into a macro and sprinkle in your code.

Alternatively, if you have multiple objects of the same class and you need to know which one had sent the signal, you can use the `sender()` function and compare object address, etc.

Comment: I came that far, however the solution for which I've opened the bounty (and which the OP asked) is for a way to get the actual line from where the signal was emitted (with the help of gdb, of course).

Comment: @Alan, I updated the answer. I can't think of any better ways at the moment

Answer (score 2):

Guessing that the signal and slot are connected through a `Qt::QueuedConnection`, I usually put a breakpoint in every emit of a signal connected to that slot in that case, if there aren't too many of them.

If you otherwise temporarily make it a `Qt::DirectConnection` (or `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` if across threads) you should be able to see the emission in the stack trace of the emitter thread, waiting for the slot to complete.

Comment: Unfortunately there are too many of them, and they need to run constantly several times per second. Having a simple string show up in the debugging session would be golden. I wonder why this is not available as an debugging aid in the debug builds of qt..